# How to clean an induction stove from overheat?

Tags: cleaning, stove, induction

After all water in teapot was boiled, an empty teapot was left on the surface and stove was turned on. You can see the spot on the photo. Is there some ways to fix or clean this?

Induction hob model BOSCH PIB673F17E.

[image] [image]

Comment: Erm, perhaps it's my screen, but I can't see a stain...?

Comment: I do, you have to look carefully, it's slightly darker in the center.

Comment: Yes, it is in the center of the ring. You can see darken color than the hob itself. In the real it looks more contrast. So, the burnt spot is not very big, so I think it could be cleaned if it on the glass surface. Do you have any experience with it?

Comment: Unless it's a lot worse than the photo makes it appear, I wonder whether it's even worth trying extensive measures to clean this. It's barely noticeable, and if it won't come off with regular cleaning then you could wind up damaging or defacing the hob some other way while trying to get this off.

Comment: Also something to consider is that potentially this isn't a surface stain, but much deeper rooted by slightly burning the ceramic itself rather than just a stain on the surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what the 'stain' is. If it's just surface deposits from the bottom of the 'teapot' (kettle?) transferred to the stove top, use a recommended proprietary cleaner (depends what country you are from what is available, ask at a hardware store for ceramic hob cleaner or induction hob cleaner). If it's in the bulk of the stove top caused by heat damage to the thickness of the material, you have two choices... live with it or replace the top. You won't be able to polish out the stain as it goes through the thickness.

Side note, that's probably why many induction hobs are black or very dark... harder to spot if there is any discolouration caused by getting a pan way too hot.

Answer (score 2):

I've got a black induction hob and left a pan on with nothing in it - hence a huge mark. My husband rubbed it with black T-cut 9Usually used for scratches on cars) and it's completely removed the stain. Phew!

Answer (score 1):

If the stain is persistent, do the following:

1. Wash the surface with soap and water and dry it completely.
2. Cover the stained area with baking soda.
3. Saturate a dishcloth with hot water and place over the baking soda.
4. Allow to sit overnight.
5. In the morning, remove and re-dampen the dishcloth with hot water and scrub the stained area using the baking soda as a polishing agent.

One time I had to do this twice to get the stain off.